# SKAction.animate with SKTextureAtlas method not animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit, subclass

SKAction.animate method isn't animating properly how do I make it work correctly.

Example animation method:

```
   let textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "example")
   var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
   var frames:[SKTexture] = []
   for index in 1 ... 4 {
       let textureName = "example_\(index)"
       let texture = textureAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
       frames.append(texture)
       textureArray = frames
       print("worked")
   }
   let animate = SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.01)
   let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(animate)
   self.run(forever)
```

its printing "worked" but in my scene its showing the red X image you get when SpriteKit can't find the requested image. is there something that I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use SKTextureAtlas for this.

Try:

Swift 3:

```
    var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
    for index in 1 ... 4 {
        let textureName = "example_\(index)"
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: textureName)
        textureArray.append(texture)
    }
    let animate = SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.01)
    let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(animate)
    self.run(forever)
```

Comment: This is bad advice,  they should be fixing their texture atlas and utilizing it.  Texture Atlases are designed to reduce the memory foot print of an application.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon im not agree, can you upload a example please?

Comment: yes please! this is not a ego challenge. I remember fail on try animate from atlas. =/

Comment: Then it is probably because you were not using your atlas correctly.  If you set up the OP code with how I have the xcatlas setup, you will see it working

Answer (score 0):

The red X means that your texture atlas is not setup correctly,  check your xcassets folder to make sure your textures are setup.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I thought that the textureAtlas was meant to be in the side-view file access thingy

Comment: Texture atlas takes all your little textures and turns it into 1 huge texture.  I like to call it a mega texture

Comment: I just realized what you said.  You mean in the project view.  No, that is the old way before it was introduced in XCAssets

Comment: so your saying it would be more effective if I move my SKTextureAtlases into the XCAssets folder?

Comment: Yes,  the way you are doing it now is the old way,  going through XCAssets gets you extra meta info you can give your texture to better define it